# Git - get last commit made on branch

Tags: git, merge, git-commit

I have a git branch, `branch-1`, whose last commit hash is `123456`. I also have a git branch `branch-2` whose last commit is `7890ab` and was made after `123456`. Both of these branches are based off of `dev`.

I then merge `branch-2` into `dev` and pull `dev` into `branch-1`. Running `git log` on branch-1 shows the last 3 commits as:

- A merge commit for pulling `dev` into `branch-1`
- `7890ab`
- `123456`

Is there a command I can run that will retrieve the last commit **made** on branch `branch-1` -- that is, `123456`? I've tried running `git log --no-merges --max-count=1`, which excludes the merge commit, but retrieves `7890ab` because it's not a "merge commit" even though it was retrieved from a separate branch.

Thank you.

Comment: The tip of the reflog for that branch?

Comment: Wait, if you pull dev while you are on branch-1 then the last commit made on branch-1 will whatever commit results from that. I think. But you can use the reflog to figure where the branch was n steps before that pull.

Comment: Why do you wish to do this? From the POV of the Git history (e.g. on a fresh clone), this is not possible. Though, as @Guildenstern points out the machine that committed to `branch-1` may have extra information in the reflogs.

Comment: Side Note, you emphasized the word "*made* on branch `branch-1`" to convey the meaning of your question, which I think is clear, but note that in Git that meaning doesn't really exist. In other words, you are interested in knowing what was the last commit "made" while `branch-1` was checked out, but imagine the scenario where you were detached when you made that commit, and then created a new branch pointing to that new commit after the fact. In that case, no commit was ever "made" on that branch, and no one could possibly ever know that (or care), except for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by using the `first-parent` flag on `git log`. From the git log documentation:

> When finding commits to include, follow only the first parent commit
> upon seeing a merge commit. This option can give a better overview
> when viewing the evolution of a particular topic branch, because
> merges into a topic branch tend to be only about adjusting to updated
> upstream from time to time, and this option allows you to ignore the
> individual commits brought in to your history by such a merge.

This resulted in a log that just showed the original `123456` commit and a merge commit, but I was able to filter out the merge commit by description (e.g. filter out any commit with description "Merge branch x into target"